# Rest Api Design for handing multiple optional parameters in one endpoint or as less endpoints as possible

Tags: java, rest, jpa, design-patterns

We want to design Rest Api with the endpoint which can handle multiple optional parameters and based on the parameter passed, do a search in the Database using JPA and fetch back the results. For Instance, let's say we have an Employee table in the database which has columns

```
EmployeeId, JoiningDate, Salary, CurrentTitle, TimeInCurrentTitle and may be few more columns.
```

For some columns as well, there could be multiple ways to search e.g.

`Fetch all employees with JoiningDate as 2022-05-04`

`or fetch all employees who joined after 2022-05-04`

Same with salary,

`get all employees having Salary as $80000`

`or get all employees having salary greater than $80000`

One Approach is to design single endpoint for each column. In the DAO layer, we are trying to use JPA to get the results from the database

```
EmployeeId -> findByEmployeeId will get the result for that id from database
JoiningDate -> findByJoiningDate will get all the empolyees who joined on that date
AfterJoiningDate -> findByJoiningDateGreaterThan will get all the employees who joined after given date
BetweenJoiningDate -> findByJoiningDateBetween will get all the employess who joined between given date A and given date B
```

We have around 10 or so columns using which a user can search and in some columns as well, there could be multiple options to search as I described above with Date and number column. We would also want to add pagination and sorting capability while retrieving the results.

If we design resource in rest Api as Employee, we can accept the input as

```
http://context-root.com/v1/employee?id=123
http://context-root.com/v1/employee?id=123&joiningDate=2022-05-04
```

and so on, but unable to think how can we simplify it from business logic layer, where we need to call appropriate back end method as per the inputs received without writing too many if else conditions which would certainly increase the cyclomatic complexity and also makes the code difficult to read.

We don't want to create too many endpoints to simplify it, so trying to understand if there's a better way for such approach so we could minimize the number of endpoints we need to expose and still get the desired outcome and keep the code readable as well.

Pls advise.

Comment: Single endpoint using https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries to eliminate combinatorial explosion induce cyclometric complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement single endpoint with dynamic filtering and sorting. E.g. your endpoint should consume something like this:

```json
{
  "filters": [
    {
      "operation": "eq",
      "field:": "EmployeeId",
      "value": "123",
      "valueType": "long"
    },
    {
      "operation": "like",
      "field:": "CurrentTitle",
      "value": "title",
      "valueType": "string"
    }
  ],
  "sorts": [
    {
      "field": "EmployeeId",
      "direction": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

You predefine set of possible operations (eq, gt, like, between etc.) and map it to JPA Criteria API. That should keep filter queries relative simply and adaptive for DB schema changes. Furthermore, you could join filters into groups to introduce more complex filtering logic.

Comment: Hi @amb1dex, the above json can be create from the UI application or directly passed into postman, but can that also be mapped to swagger-ui somehow? I had hard time finding answer to that when I came across one similar implementation.

Comment: Hi. json I provided is more like sample to begin with. Of course, you could pass it into Postman or write Java POJO to represent it and use Jackson or Gson for serialization. If you prefer Swagger form, it also could easily build in it [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/K5y8nTdT)